# How do I find my Artifactory server ID?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I'm using `jfrog rt config` to configure JFrog CLI. It asks for my "Artifactory server ID". I can't find any information about this in the JFrog documentation or on my Artifactory instance. How do I find this server ID?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The meaning of that field is for you to give this instance a name.

Just pick a name for this instance and rock on :)